# Sharing Data Between Partial Views

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a Breadcrumb navigation that allows users to toggle between two partial views (pvA and pvB).

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="toggleBreadcrumb(1)">pvA</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ng-click="toggleBreadcrumb(2)">pvB</a></li>
    </ol>

    <div id="pvA" name="pvA" ng-if="partialViewIdToShow === 1">
        @Html.Partial("_pvA")
    </div>
    <div id="pvB" name="pvB" ng-if="partialViewIdToShow === 2">
        @Html.Partial("_pvB")
    </div>
```

What is best practice to share data between these two views?

The data shared between the two views comes from the same database table.

If data is added to pvA it should be available in pvB and visa versa.

Comment: Just supply both with the same model.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback mxmissile. I have both partial views using the same model. What I was hoping for was when say a date is changed on pvA that change is reflected in pvB when toggled and when toggling back to pvA the data entered is still there. All this without having to submit to the database.

Comment: that would be for the [angularjs] experts in the house, sorry I was not much help.

Comment: Maybe you can accomplish something like that with signalR...or using ajax

Comment: Thank you Hackman. I read up on signalR and Data Services. Would you suggest singalR over a Service?

Comment: Here is a simple example of the Service in use. http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/05/04/how-to-share-data-between-controllers-in-the-angularjs.aspx

Comment: @MWheater82 since your already in angular land, I think you should be able to use angular to accomplish this